# How to change position of hardcoded elements on condition in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm writing a template and calling that particular template and I'm hard coding few new elements and I want these hard coded elements in my xslt to display in the result output in an order as shown in my desired output below. How can I write this condition ?

Here is my input request:

```
<companies>
  <company>
    <locations>
      <location>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <empdetails>
          <empdetail>
            <x>A</x>
            <y>B</y>
          </empdetail>
        </empdetails>
        <empdetails>
          <empdetail>
            <x>A1</x>
            <y>B1</y>
          </empdetail>
        </empdetails>     
      </location>
    </locations>
    <locations>
      <location>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <empdetails>
          <empdetail>
            <x>A2</x>
            <y>B2</y>
          </empdetail>
        </empdetails>
        <empdetails>
          <empdetail>
            <x>A3</x>
            <y>B3</y>
          </empdetail>
        </empdetails>
      </location>
    </locations>
  </company>
</companies>
```

Here is the desired output:

```
<employeeinfo>
  <employees>
    <employee>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <details>
        <detail>
          <A>A</A>
          <B>B</B>
        </detail>
      </details>
      <details>
        <detail>
          <A>A1</A>
          <B>B1</B>
        </detail>
      </details>
    </employee>
  </employees>
  <employees>
    <employee>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <details>
        <detail>
          <A>A2</A>
          <B>B2</B>
        </detail>
      </details>
      <details>
        <detail>
          <A>A3</A>
          <B>B3</B>
        </detail>
      </details>
    </employee>
  </employees>
</employeeinfo>
```

Output which I'm getting:

```
    <employeeinfo>
    <employees>
    <employee>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <details>
      <detail>
        <A>A</A>
        <B>B</B>
     </detail>
    </details>
    </employee>
    </employees>
    <employees>
    <employee>
     <ID>1</ID>
    <details>
      <detail>
        <A>A1</A>
        <B>B1</B>
     </detail>
    </details>
    </employee>
    </employees>
    <employees>
    <employee>
     <ID>2</ID>
    <details>
      <detail>
        <A>A2</A>
        <B>B2</B>
     </detail>
    </details>
    </employee>
    </employees>
    <employees>
    <employee>
     <ID>2</ID>
    <details>
      <detail>
        <A>A3</A>
        <B>B3</B>
     </detail>
    </details>
    </employee>
    </employees>
    </employeeinfo>
```

This is how I'm writing my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" 
    indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="companies">
    <employeeinfo>  
      <employees>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()=locations]/*[local-name()=location]/*[local-name()=empdetails]">
          <xsl:call-template name="locations">
            <xsl:with-param name="employee" select="."/>
            
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </employees>
    </employeeinfo>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="locations">
    <xsl:param name="employee"/>
    <xsl:variable name="A" select=".//empdetail/x"/>
    <xsl:variable name="B" select=".//empdetail/y"/>
    <xsl:variable name="C" select="../locations/ID"/>
    <employee>
      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="$C"/>
      </ID>
      <details>
        <detail>
          <A>
            <xsl:value-of select="$A"/>
          </A>
          <B>
            <xsl:value-of select="$B"/>
          </B>
        </detail>
      </details>
    </employee>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you do us the favour to indent the input and output samples, to allow us to see the nesting?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to XSLT. How to do it ?

Comment: Well, if you don't know how to use XSLT then use any pretty printer, indenter and not XSLT, just try to make the input somehow readable to other people that are not familiar with the document type you are showing and trying to process.

Comment: I will indent the XML file. It is tricky because the OP included TABS into it, messing the indentation. I will use an external utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you nearly want a one to one mapping, only skipping one element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="companies">
    <employeeinfo>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </employeeinfo>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="company">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="locations">
    <employees>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </employees>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="location">
    <employee>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </employee>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="empdetails">
    <details>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </details>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="empdetail">
    <detail>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </detail>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x">
    <A>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </A>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="y">
    <B>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </B>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: sad part is I can't use template match in my xslt. It's not working.

Comment: If the input is as posted then the code shown does work. If the input has any namespace declarations you failed to show then edit the input in your question and also in the output to show any namespace declarations. Also state whether you use or can use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.

Comment: no changes in input or output. But I can't use <xsl:template match> in the middle of the xslt. It's an existing requirement. Is their any possibility that we can achieve this without using <xsl:template match>?

Comment: Good luck then, but don't pretend you want to use XSLT.

Comment: Don't tell us it "isn't working", tell us how it fails, and tell us in more detail how you are running it. The code is correct, changing it to avoid using `xsl:template` isn't going to address your problem, because you've misdiagnosed the problem.

Comment: Ours is a lengthy code with multiple template names and call-templates. It's an existing requirement. I'm not saying above code isn't working. Please don't take me wrong. It's not working in my xslt. We are not allowed to do make more changes by creating new templates. So I want to write any other condition within the template itself if possible. currently we are extending the mapping. So I'm stuck !